# Jquery getElementsByClassName for selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to use getElementsByClassName for a set of selected rows?

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `getElementsByClassName` is entirely independent of the current selection.  That subset of `document.getElementsByClassName("foo")` that is currently selected can be obtained by

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var selectedElements = [];
for (element of document.getElementsByClassName("foo") {
  // second argument of containsNode true means elements
  // partly but not entirely within selection will be
  // included.  False would filter for those elements
  // entirely within the selection.
  if (selection.containsNode(element, true))
    selectedElements.push(element);
}
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode

Answer (score 0):

Before post in this forum, please, read the documentations, or, search other similar subjects for find your solution!

You've the official DOM documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/dom.html#getelementsbyclassname) for the getElementsByClassName...

Also, you are taged your post with "Javascript" and "JQuery" Tags.

JQuery using Javascript. the function getElementByclassName is javascript problem, not Jquery.

**Select lot of row with Javascript and getElementByClassname() and change background-Color of them:**

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='trClass' >
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='trClass' >
            <td>Other Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="changeAllRowsColor()" value="changeColor" />
```

100% javascript:

```
<script>
    function changeAllRowsColor(){
        var allRows = document.getElementsByClassName('trClass');
        var i = allRows.length;
        while(i--) {
            allRows[i].style.backgroundColor = "#FCC";
        }
    }
</script>
```

**the Same with 100% Jquery:**

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="changeColor" value="changeColor" />
```

100% JQuery:

```
<script>
    $('#changeColor').click(function(){
        $('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','#fcc');
        }
    });
</script>
```

**and the Same with 50% Jquery and Javascript for performance:**

html:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Other Something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="changeColor()" value="changeColor" />
```

100% JQuery:

```
<script>
    function changeColor(){
        $('tr').each(function(){
            $(this).css('background-color','#fcc');
        }
    });
</script>
```

You've lot of great tutorials on the web :

W3School tutorial for Javascript is [here](http://changeColor)

Official JQuery Documentation is [here](https://api.jquery.com)

Javascript informations from stackeoverflow is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)

Know how to use stackoverflow.com in 2min is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) !